# Java Android Studio: Image View not loading from Drawable folder

Tags: java, android

I've been working on a simple java application, and wanted to add a logo as the homescreen is fairly empty. I tried using an image view, and after it didn't work I googled tutorials to make sure I was initiating it correctly. I didn't see any difference, but the actual image wouldn't load.

Xml code for image view:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src = "@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtBody"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtBody"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtBody"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:maxHeight="600dp"
            android:maxWidth="600dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:clickable="false" />
```

And here's a picture of the layout preview (With an arrow pointing to the outline of where it should be, and the resource circled in the correct folder) along with a picture of the logo
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any dice if you add

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"

android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Edit: also are we sure nothing is overlapping it?

Comment: I'll try that code in one second. As for overlay: Yes I'm positive. Nothing else is in that position in this frame layout, and all the other frame layouts are set to invisible until called upon.(Checked this already to make sure)

Comment: Nah still no dice, didn't change anything.

Comment: Still not sure what's wrong: Deleted and then remade the drawable folder, downloaded a new copy of the image, deleted the text view, and added the text view back in with code rather than GUI editor. Something in there fixed it, thanks anyway.